# handling multiple input switch using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

**1. Description**

I am creating multiple switches on a table using React JS. The purpose of this table is to determine the user role of an account.

[image]

**2. Problem**

However, I encountered some obstacles when creating it:

1. When one switch is clicked, all of them are clicked

**4. Question**

How do I fix this program bug? I hope to be able to click on one switch without disturbing the other switches

**5. Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import { Table, Form, } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function RoleForm() {
  const [lihatChecked, toggleLihat] = useReducer((checked) => !checked, false);
  const [ubahChecked, toggleUbah] = useReducer((checked) => !checked, false);
  const [tambahChecked, toggleTambah] = useReducer((checked) => !checked, false);
  const [hapusChecked, toggleHapus] = useReducer((checked) => !checked, false);
  const [eksportChecked, toggleEksport] = useReducer((checked) => !checked, false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log([lihatChecked, ubahChecked, tambahChecked, hapusChecked, eksportChecked])
  }, [lihatChecked, ubahChecked, tambahChecked, hapusChecked, eksportChecked])

  const tableHeader = [
    "No",
    "Menu",
    "Sub Menu",
    "Lihat",
    "Tambah",
    "Ubah",
    "Hapus",
    "Export",
  ];

  const tableData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      menu: "Dashboard",
      submenu: ["-"],
      perms: ["lihat", null, null, null, "export"],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      menu: "Konfigurasi/Pengaturan",
      submenu: ["Akun Pengguna", "Grup", "Antrian", "Rawat"],
      perms: ["lihat", "tambah", "edit", "hapus", null],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Table className="table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {tableHeader.map((header, index) => (
            <th
              key={index}
              className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold text-center"
              style={{ padding: "0.75rem" }}
            >
              {header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {tableData.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <React.Fragment key={rowIndex}>
            <tr>
              <td>{rowIndex + 1}</td>
              <td>{row.menu}</td>
              <td>
                <Form.Check type="switch" checked={lihatChecked} onChange={toggleLihat}/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <Form.Check type="switch" checked={tambahChecked} onChange={toggleTambah}/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {row.submenu.slice(1).map((subMenu, subMenuIndex) => (
              <tr key={`${rowIndex}-${subMenuIndex}`}>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{subMenu}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

here's the codesandbox link :

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-microservice-75h47y

**Add temporary result**

the layout goes like this :

[image]

Comment: You are using a single state for all switches, which is causing the issue.

Comment: can you help me for fixing the issues sir ? , i'm edited my question so that there is codesandbox link

Comment: I will not write component for you. You got good answer, use it.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one record of e.g. `lihatChecked` so clicking one lihat will click them all.

There are many ways of solving this, I would recommend you make a new component which you call for each row.

e.g.:

```js
const RoleRow = ({ index, menu, submenu }) => {
  const [lihatChecked, toggleLihat] = useReducer((checked) => !checked, false);
  const [tambahChecked, toggleTambah] = useReducer((checked) => !checked, false);
  return (
    <>
      <tr>
        <td>{index}</td>
        <td>{menu}</td>
        <td>
          <Form.Check type="switch" checked={lihatChecked} onChange={toggleLihat} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Form.Check type="switch" checked={tambahChecked} onChange={toggleTambah} />
        </td>
      </tr>
      {submenu.slice(1).map((subMenuItem, subMenuItemIndex) => (
        <tr key={`${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>{subMenuItem}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

And use the component like this:

```js
<tbody>
  {tableData.map((row, rowIndex) => (
    <React.Fragment key={rowIndex}>
      <RoleRow index={rowIndex + 1} menu={row.menu} submenu={row.submenu} />
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, it works. i have a question sir, how to make all submenu have input switch ?

Comment: same again - add the Form.Check inside your subMenu. make another component to go within your submenu.slice.map().

Comment: i'm edit the question sir. can you help me for fix the layout and also fix the bug when clicking switch ?

Comment: here's the codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-microservice-75h47y